# Find if date is less than 7 days from now

Tags: php, date, if-statement, strtotime

How can i find out if expiry date is less than 7 days from now?

The expiry date format looks like this: **2016-04-13**

I have a code here, but it doesn't work:

```
if($record->$c < date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 day'))){
   // this is true
}
```

Hope anyone could help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just convert both units to unix timestamp, make your subtraction, then divide it by 86400:

```
$expiry_date = '2016-04-18';
$today = time();
$interval = strtotime($expiry_date) - $today;
$days = floor($interval / 86400); // 1 day
if($days < 7) {
    echo 'less';
}
```

Or another way with `DateTime` classes:

```
$expiry_date = '2016-04-18';
$expiry_date = new DateTime($expiry_date);
$today = new DateTime();
$interval = $today->diff($expiry_date);
$day = $interval->format('%r%a');
if($day < 7) {
    echo 'less';
}
```

Example conditions:

```
$expiry_date = '2016-04-18';
$today = time();
$interval = strtotime($expiry_date) - $today;
$day = floor($interval / 86400); // 1 day
if($day >= 1 && $day < 7) {
    echo 'between 1 - 7 days';
} elseif($day <= 0) {
    echo 'deadline';
} else {
    echo 'soon';
}
```

Just change / tweak it depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: i tried the latter code @Ghost, it seems to be working that it will echo less on the future date that is less than 7 days from now, but it will also appear the echo less on the past date 7 days from now.

Comment: @zen just make another condition for that, of course, if will go past that if you're beyond the expiry date. i just illustrated the basic comparison of it, compare unix timestamps or use datetime

Comment: @zen just add like in between 1 and 7, then if its negative just say its past expiry date or something

Comment: i see @Ghost, thanks a lot for the inputs. I think its almost there, can you help me out a little bit ghost if you don't mind? Been trying to figure this one out 2 days already. I am not good on comparing unix timestamps.

Comment: thanks a lot @Ghost, you don't know what i am going through just to find a solution on this one. Thumbs UP! +10 :)

Answer (score 1):

Recommend exploring `date_diff()` function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php

My challenge was different:

```
// Count days is date range 
function count_days_in_range($date1, $date2) {

    $date1      = date_create($date1);
    $date2      = date_create($date2);

    $interval   = date_diff($date1, $date2);
    $days       = $interval->days;

    return $days;
}
```

But this function will make your life much easier.